# Which forum CMS lets authors moderate their own topics?

Tags: cms, forum

Hello I'm looking for a forum software to install on my website, that could let any author of a new topic moderate its topic with the same rights as a regular moderator, mostly by editing other members' replies.

I've joined a hundred of BBS (running most softwares) and none of them let the authors be moderate their own thread. Therefore I assumed it was not a built in feature, possibly because pyramidal moderation was the only one known to developers.

If there are too many forum CMS with this feature then I'm looking for one very modern, in the spirit of Discourse but in PHP.

Comment: I think there is a lot. I suggest to narrow your question (which system, framework or similar).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica can you name any ?